# Is the sum of two (non-real) random variables necessarily a random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Please note that I'm working with the following definition of random variable, which allows for a codomain other than $\mathbb{R}$.

**Definition:** Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $(\Omega', \mathcal{F}')$ a measurable space. Then a random variable is a [$\mathcal{F}/\mathcal{F}'$-measurable mapping](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Measurable_Mapping) $f: \Omega \to \Omega'$.

I know that for $(\Omega', \mathcal{F}') = (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$, the sum of two random variables on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ is also a random variable on the same probability space. Indeed, there are already proofs of this theorem here on Math.SE. But that leaves the following question open.

---

**Question:**

- Is it generally true that the sum of two random variables is a random
  variable?
- If not, what's a simple counterexample?

Comment: Take a ball from an urn with red and green as possible outcomes and toss a coin (Heads or Tails).  Then try to add the outcomes together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample:

Let $\Omega'$ be some set equipped with $\sigma$-algebra $\{\varnothing,\Omega'\}$ and let it be that there is no further structure present on $\Omega'$.

Then automatically every function $f:\Omega\to\Omega'$ is measurable but $f+f$ is not even defined.